# Equivalent of `exclusion` in sequel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sequel

What is the Sequel equivalent of "exclusion"?

For a simple example, in Active Record:

```
validates :subdomain, exclusion: { in: %w(www us ca jp),
    message: "%{value} is reserved." }
```

How can this be written in Sequel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequel doesn't provide the exclusion helper by default, but you could customize it yourself.

```
class Host < Sequel::Model
  def validate
    super
    errors.add(:subdomain, "#{subdomain} is reserved.") if %w(www us ca jp).include?(subdomain)
  end
end
```

See "[Custom Validations](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/3ee3373dd81b9ad85ed224d13635c75827647f32/doc/validations.rdoc#custom-validations)" for more information.